# Visual studio silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is it possible to host a silverlight 4 application with iis 5 because i am using windows xp.  or are there other ways to host silverlight application without iis

Answer (score 1):

When you use Visual Studio 2010, you get a Development Server, cassini. That is more than enough to host Silverlight and you should be good. You just need to use FileSystem while you are creating the project.

It can also be hosted on your IIS Server if you wish to. Basically, your Silverlight Application as such would end up being a XAP file which is nothing more than a ZIP file with a proper manifest in it which says what to download. Silverlight Plugin that is in your web page takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Any web server that can, ahem..., serve .xap files can host a Silverlight application, it could even be an Apache server on Linux :-)

Comment: By ahem I guess you mean that can handle non standard file extensions but they all can, can't they?

Comment: They all can for sure. I just was trying (and miserably failing, it appears) to make fun of myself saying "any web server... serves" :-).